# How to improve performance of SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: 2013

I have a site running on SharePoint 2013 server having ram of 32 GB. My SQL server has ram of 64 GB. Both have more than 100 GB HDD. When I setup my site it was loaded in 10-12 seconds. But now the opening time for any page is 25-30 seconds. I have checked it with chrome and it shows me following result:

[image]

I have cleared log of my both servers. Even I have executed warm up script on my application server. But performance of site is still down. I have googled this issue and found in some blog that shutting down Distribution Catch service might help. But it will stop other functionalities too. So we are not in support of it. Other solution we found was to increase ram for distribution catch. But even that didn't help. As the last solution I am asking for any help or guidance how can I improve the performance?

Comment: Use Fiddler or you could enable developer dashboard. Developer tools that says that it takes 27 seconds is not very helpful, fiddler are more detailed so you can see what is taking so much time like any resource, script, image, authentication etc.

Comment: Do you have any custom solution / resources added to the home page? Does it take the same amount of time when you go to SharePoint settings page / Site contents page? Do as @user19952 says and let us know the results.

Comment: @user19952 I have checked my request in fiddler. It request 111 items in page and most of them are loaded withing couple of seconds. Only the http header call takes 12 seconds.

Comment: @Akhoy I load the settings page and the performance was same. Fiddler shows only few request but the time taken was same. But when I open site content page then it was lightning fast. Fiddler shows only one request for it. I didn't get it. can you explain it?

Comment: What kind of customizations have you done in your environment? Custom master pages, css, images? Web calls?

Comment: Yes we have created a master page with background image of 45 KB and custom css and js.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience almost all performance issues that I have experienced in the past have been related to the Distributed Cache service.

When I come across an environment that is slow and it is not obvious why, one of the first things I do is delete the Distributed Cache service and create it again. This resolves the issue 95% of the time.

This is the best guide I have found on managing the Distributed Cache service, and I continue to use it today:

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/11/27/managing-the-distributed-cache-service-in-sharepoint-2013/

Failing this, have a look at some of these other suggestions:

http://davidlozzi.com/2013/01/16/my-users-dont-like-sharepoint-because-it-is-too-slow/

Answer (score 1):

Use Developer Dashboard to determine what items on the page are loading slowly. It can be anything, such as: extensive use of CQWP on the page, User Profile service having issues, authentication issues.

If not that, please describe what you have on the page and if that could be a "valid" reason for the slow down.

Comment: I have added few list view web part on home page. There is a custom web part which fetch user data and display any birthday. Then there is a google map of our location which is loaded last and takes around 4 sec to load

Comment: Try closing web parts to determine which one (if any) is causing the slowness.